# Do Szego Kernel in one variable by fixing another variable in a $C^{\infty}$ bounded domain is Bounded?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be any $C^{\infty}$ bounded domain. Let  $ S(.,.)$ denotes the Szego Kenel of Holomorphic Hardy Space $H^2(\partial\Omega)$. Then for $w\in\Omega$ do $S(.,w)$ is a bounded function on $\Omega$? Or in what condition on $\Omega$ it can be bounded?